# Route OpenVPN client traffic to a proxy? (iptables magic needed??)

Tags: iptables, openvpn, ubuntu-16.04

I have an OpenVPN server running on a VPS with OpenVPN client running on my router on my home network. I'm trying to route my clients traffic over a proxy after it reaches the OpenVPN server so my vps ip is not exposed.. Can this be done with the iptables? I've tried a few steps from articles and forum posts I've read around the internet but nothing is working yet.

This is a diagram of my intended functionality.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kg2x.jpg

Thanks for any advice.